# Unit Test and xctool : cannot copy from bundle

Tags: ios, xctool

I am using jenkins and xctool to continuously build and run unit tests on my iOS App.
As I am using a sqlite database, in unit tests the very first thing I am doing is to copy the template database from assets (contained in the bundle) to the documents directory.

All these work very well in Xcode, on both my local machine and on the continuous delivery server.

Unfortunately, the file is not copied when using xctool, it says that the operation couldn't be completed as the file does not exist. When examining the paths printed by xctool, file and paths do exist :(

I am totally stucked with this issue.
I hope one SO master will be helpful.

Thank you to all !